# How to solve this probabilty pizza delivery problem?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The company PizzaGo charges 6 dollars for one pizza.
The delivery time $T$ is an exponential random variable with mean value $=m$

The company considers that a pizza's been delivered on time if $T < 2m$.
If the delivery time is bigger than $2m$, the client gets the pizza for free.
Moreover, if the delivery time is bigger than $3m$ PizzaGo gives the client a 2 dollar dessert.

a) What is the mean profit for delivered pizza?

b) From 70 delivered pizzas, what is the mean number of pizzas delivered on time? 
What's the probability of not delivering more than 20% of pizzas on time?

c) Two independent pizza delivery men gave their pizzas on time. What is the probability that the sum of their delivery times is less than $3m$?

I've been having trouble doing this exercise. I don't know how to tackle it.
What I did is to find the $F_T(t)$ and the $f_T(t)$ substituting $\lambda$ for $1/m$ in the formula. The distribution and density functions are:

$F_T(t)= 1 - e^\frac{-x}{m}$ and $f_T(t) = \frac {1}{m} e^{\frac{-x}{m}}$

a) ?

b) I don't know if it is the right way to do it. What I did is to find $F_T(2) = 1 - e^\frac{-2m}{m} = 0.864664 $ and multiply it by 70, which equals $60.5$
 I also found $F_T(t>3) = 1 - (1 - e^\frac{-3m}{m}) = 0.0497870 $ and $F_T(2<t<3) = F_T(3)-F_T(2) = 0.950212 - 0.864664 = 0.08545 $

The probability that the pizza isn't delivered on time is $1 - F_T(2) = 0.135336$ I didn't know how to apply it to find the $>20%$ pizzas that aren't delivered on time.

c) I think I need to find a function $S$ that is the sum of the delivery times of each man. $ S=T_1 + T_2 $ . But I couldn't work it out.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint for a:** The profit $Y$ is a discrete random variable that takes values in $\{-2, 0, 6\}$ and has pmf $$P(Y=y)=\begin{cases}P(T<2m), & y=6\\ P(2m\le T \le 3m), & y=0 \\ P(3m<T), & y=-2 \end{cases}$$ Thus the expected profit is equal to $$\begin{align*}E[Y]&=6\cdot P(T<2m)+0\cdot P(2m<T<3m)+(-2)\cdot P(3m<T)\\&=6\cdot F_T(2m)-2(1-F_T(3m))\end{align*}$$

**Hint for b:** The number $N$ of pizzas delivered on time among $70$ pizzas is a binomial random variable with parameters $n=70$ and $p=F_T(2m)=0.864664$ as you have calculated. You want to find

1. $E[N]=np$ and
2. $P(N\le 0.2\cdot 70)=P(N \le 14)$. (This can involve some tedious calculations).

**Hint for c:** You can use the fact that the sum of independent exponential random variables with parameter $1/m$ has the [Erlang distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution).